# print the student name and the score of student in python3

Tags: python

I want to print the name of student and the score of student but i have a problem

here is the code

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter

A = 'Ali'
AV = 19.75
M = 'Mohammad'
MV = 19.64
C = 'Cacurs'
CV = 19.50

Name_Ave = {C:CV, M:MV, A:AV}
D = OrderedDict(sorted(Name_Ave.items(), key = itemgetter(1)))


for Keys in D.keys():
    for Values in D.values():
        print('%s Average is: %s' %(Keys, Values))
```

----and here is the out

```
Cacurs Average is: 19.5
Cacurs Average is: 19.64
Cacurs Average is: 19.75
Mohammad Average is: 19.5
Mohammad Average is: 19.64
Mohammad Average is: 19.75
Ali Average is: 19.5
Ali Average is: 19.64
Ali Average is: 19.75
```

what can I do ??
please help me

Comment: `for key, value in D.items():`?

Comment: Or access the value *using* the key.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = 'Ali'
AV = 19.75
M = 'Mohammad'
MV = 19.64
C = 'Cacurs'
CV = 19.50

Name_Ave = {C:CV, M:MV, A:AV}
for item in Name_Ave:
    print(item+' score is : '+str(Name_Ave[item]))
```

Comment: if u feel that this is right then u can accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

Right now what you're doing is for each Key in D, you're printing all the values in your dictionary. So for each student, you're running through a loop of all the grades in your dictionary, hence why it prints each grade for each student.

What should be doing is iterating through each key/value pair:

```
for key, value in D.items():
    print('%s Average is: %s' %(key, value))
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be this one:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter

A = 'Ali'
AV = 19.75
M = 'Mohammad'
MV = 19.64
C = 'Cacurs'
CV = 19.50

Name_Ave = {C:CV, M:MV, A:AV}
D = OrderedDict(sorted(Name_Ave.items(), key = itemgetter(1)))


for Keys,Values in zip(D.keys(),D.values()):
        print('%s Average is: %s' %(Keys, Values))
```

As pointed by @Daniel Mesejo, you can change the for cycle as following:

```py
for key, value in D.items():
        print('%s Average is: %s' %(key,value))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use sorted(Name_Ave.items()) if you want to print the average score by ordering the names.

```
for (name, average) in sorted(Name_Ave.items()): 
    print("The average of {name} is {average}".format(name=name, average=average))
```